# How to tell options_for_select field where to save selected option value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm returning to Rails after almost 5 years away and building out a personal project. In my `_form.html.erb` file, I'm trying to use a  field, but the data never gets saved where I think it will be.

```
<select>
  <%= options_for_select([['black'], ['blue'], ['red']], :selected => :color) %>
</select>
```

In my index, when I try to use `model.color` I get nothing returned. I'm sure its something basic I'm not getting, but for some reason Google searches and example code doesn't look like exactly like what I got. I'm not sure what option to pass to tell the form where to save the selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the `select` tag a name (e.g. `<select name="foo">` populates `params[:foo]`, `<select name="foo[bar]">` populates `params[:foo][:bar]`; alternatively use the `select_tag`/`select` form helper methods – see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag and https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select).

Be aware: If you haven't used Rails for several years, chances are you don't know about **strong parameters** which you need to use if you want to do direct assignment (e.g. `User.new(params[:user])` doesn't work as it used to in older Rails versions – you need to use strong parameters here). Details: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the input a name in order to do anything meaningful with it - This is not Rails specific. Its universally true for web development. Form data in HTTP is just a bunch of key value pairs and the name attribute sets the key.

In Rails you should use the form builders and input helpers unless you have a very good reason not to - it is after driven by convention over configuration. They will handle assigning the name attribute for you:

```
<%= form_with(model: @thing) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :color, [['Black','black'], ['Blue','blue'], ['Red', 'red']] %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

This renders something like:

```
<select name="things[color]">
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  # ...
</select>
```

And would give you the following params hash:

```
{
  thing: {
    color: 'black'
  }
}
```

They also provide data bindings between your model and the form so that the inputs are not reset when the user submits an invalid form.

I would really start by reading [the rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-basic-forms) as you have a lot to catch up on.

Comment: Additionally you're using the `selected=` attribute wrong. It should be a equal to the value of an option in the select `selected="black"` for example to preselect an option.